# $_POST isn't getting values from the form

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, sql-server

`$_POST` is not getting any values and i have tried a lot of procedure already mentioned on stack overflow but they are not working for me. I have tried printing the `$_POST` it is empty. i need some suggestions on it..please help

It was previously working when it was in mysql database but i tried to change the database to sqlserver and now its not working but i am not understanding i have not made any changes to this particular code and i have seen this also that it is not being affected by some other file.

there is no mistake in empty condition i wrote it myself to check whether it was empty or not and it was always showing empty whether i submit data or not

i am attaching some codes which are related to this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'config.php'; 
?>
<?php 
 if(empty($_POST)){
  echo "hello";
  try {
   $user_obj = new Cl_User();
   $data = $user_obj->registration( $_POST );
   if($data){
    $_SESSION['success'] = USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS;
    header('Location: index.php');exit;
   }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
  }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="php quiz script, php quiz code, php quiz application, quiz php code, php quiz system, online quiz using php, quiz using php, how to make quiz in php, quiz system in php, php programming quiz, online quiz using php and sqlsrv, create online quiz using php and sqlsrv, create quiz using php sqlsrv, php quiz script free">
    <meta name="keywords" content="php quiz script, php quiz code, php quiz application, quiz php code, php quiz system, online quiz using php, quiz using php, how to make quiz in php, quiz system in php, php programming quiz, online quiz using php and sqlsrv, create online quiz using php and sqlsrv, create quiz using php sqlsrv, php quiz script free">
    <title>PHP Quiz Script</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="login-form">
   <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>
   
   <h1 class="text-center">PHP Quiz Application</h1>
   <div class="form-header">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   </div>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-register" role="form" id="register-form">
    <div>
     <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" > 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
   </form>
   <div class="form-footer">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot password? </a>
     
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <a href="index.php"> Sign In </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /container -->

 
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php unset($_SESSION['success'] ); unset($_SESSION['error']);  ?>
```

```html
<?php

 $server="NIKUNJ";
   $ci = array("Database" => "My database","UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"sql@123","Characterset"=>"UTF-8") or die( "check db connect1" );
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$ci) or die ( "check db connect2" ) ;

function mssql_escape($str)
{
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
   {
    $str= stripslashes($str);
   }
   return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}

function mssql_insert_id() { 
    $id = 0; 
    $res = sqlsrv_query("SELECT @@identity AS id"); 
    if ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, MSSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        $id = $row["id"]; 
    } 
    return $id; 
} 

class Cl_User
{
 /**
  * @var will going contain database connection
  */
 protected $_con;
 
 /**
  * it will initalize DBclass
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
  $db = new Cl_DBclass();
  $this->_con = $db->con;
 }
 
 /**
  * this will handles user registration process
  * @param array $data
  * @return boolean true or false based success 
  */
 public function registration( array $data )
 {
  echo "hello";
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   
   
   // escape variables for security
   $name = mssql_escape( $trimmed_data['name'] );
   $password = mssql_escape( $trimmed_data['password'] );
   $cpassword = mssql_escape( $trimmed_data['confirm_password'] );
   
   
   // Check for an email address:
   if (filter_var( $trimmed_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = mssql_escape( $trimmed_data['email']);
   } else {
    throw new Exception( "Please enter a valid email address!" );
   }
   
   
   if((!$name) || (!$email) || (!$password) || (!$cpassword) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   if ($password !== $cpassword) {
    throw new Exception( PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password, created) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', '$password', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
   if(sqlsrv_query($this->_con, $query)){
    sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
    return true;
   };
  } else{
   throw new Exception( USER_REGISTRATION_FAIL );
  }
 }
 /**
  * This method will handle user login process
  * @param array $data
  * @return boolean true or false based on success or failure
  */
 public function login( array $data )
 {
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   // escape variables for security
   $email = mssql_escape( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
   $password = mssql_escape( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );
   if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
    throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "SELECT id, name, email, created FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
   $result = sqlsrv_query($this->_con, $query);
   $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
   $count = SQLSRV_num_rows($result);
   echo $count;
   sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
   if( $count == 1){
    $_SESSION = $data;
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    return true;
   }else{
    throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This will shows account information and handles password change
  * @param array $data
  * @throws Exception
  * @return boolean
  */
 
 public function account( array $data )
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   // escape variables for security
   $password = mssql_escape( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['password'] );
   $cpassword = $trimmed_data['confirm_password'];
   $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
   if((!$password) || (!$cpassword) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   if ($password !== $cpassword) {
    throw new Exception( PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE id = '$user_id'";
   if(sqlsrv_query($this->_con, $query)){
    sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
    return true;
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This handle sign out process
  */
 public function logout()
 {
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['success'] = LOGOUT_SUCCESS;
  header('Location: index.php');
 }
 
 /**
  * This reset the current password and send new password to mail
  * @param array $data
  * @throws Exception
  * @return boolean
  */
 public function forgetPassword( array $data )
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   
   // escape variables for security
   $email = mssql_escape( $this->_con, trim( $data['email'] ) );
   
   if((!$email) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   $password = $this->randomPassword();
   $password1 = md5( $password );
   $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password1' WHERE email = '$email'";
   if(sqlsrv_query($this->_con, $query)){
    sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "New Password Request";
    $txt = "Your New Password ".$password;
    $headers = "From: rahul.ranjan72@hotmail.com" . "\r\n" .
      "CC:rahul.ranjan72@hotmail.com";
     
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    return true;
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This will generate random password
  * @return string
  */
 
 private function randomPassword()
 {
  $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
  $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
  $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
   $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
   $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
  }
  return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
 }
 
 public function pr($data = '' )
 {
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
 }
 
 public function getCategory()
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)  or die(SQLSRV_errors());
  $categories = array();
  while ( $result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
   echo $result['id'];
   $categories[$result['id']] = $result['category_name'];
  }
  return $categories;
 }
 
 public function getQuestions(array $data)
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
    
   // escape variables for security
   $category_id = mssql_escape( $this->_con, trim( $data['category'] ) );
   if((!$category_id) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
   $query = "INSERT INTO scores ( user_id,right_answer,category_id)VALUES ( '$user_id',0,'$category_id')";
   sqlsrv_query( $this->_con, $query);
   $_SESSION['score_id'] = mssql_insert_id();
   $results = array();
   $number_question = $_POST['num_questions'];
   $total_question = $_POST['total_num_questions'];
   $row = sqlsrv_query( $this->_con, "select * from questions where category_id=$category_id ORDER BY RAND()");
   $check=SQLSRV_num_rows($row);
   if($check<$total_question)
    $rowcount=$check;
   else
   $rowcount = $total_question;
   $remainder = $rowcount/$number_question;
   $results['number_question'] = $number_question;
   $results['remainder'] = $remainder;
   $results['rowcount'] = $rowcount;
   while ( $result = SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC($row) ) {
    $results['questions'][] = $result;
   }
   sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
   return $results;
  } else{
   throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 public function getAnswers(array $data)
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   $right_answer=0;
   $wrong_answer=0;
   $unanswered=0;
   $total_question = $_POST['total_num_questions'];
   $keys=array_keys($data);
   $order=join(",",$keys);
   $query = "select id,answer from questions where id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)";
   $response=sqlsrv_query( $this->_con, $query)   or die(SQLSRV_errors());
   
   $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
   $score_id = $_SESSION['score_id'];
   while($result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($response)){
    if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
     $right_answer++;
    }else if($data[$result['id']]=='smart_quiz'){
     $unanswered++;
    }
    else{
     $wrong_answer++;
    }
   }
   $results = array();
   $results['right_answer'] = $right_answer;
   $results['wrong_answer'] = $wrong_answer;
   $results['unanswered'] = $unanswered;
   $update_query = "update scores set right_answer='$right_answer', wrong_answer = '$wrong_answer', unanswered = '$unanswered' where user_id='$user_id' and id ='$score_id' ";
   sqlsrv_query( $this->_con, $update_query)   or die(SQLSRV_errors());
   sqlsrv_close($this->_con);
   return $results;
  } 
 }
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
@author vetripandi
@copyright http:www.vetbossel.in
 */

require_once 'messages.php';

//site specific configuration declartion

define( 'DB_HOST', 'NIKUNJ' );
define( 'DB_USERNAME', 'sa');
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'sql@123');
define( 'DB_NAME', 'user_login');

function __autoload($class)
{
 $parts = explode('_', $class);
 $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$parts);
 require_once $path . '.php';
}
```

[its the image of the data i am sending but `$_POST` is not getting any values and nothing happens after signup button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8c4u.png)

Comment: you have to check `if(!empty($_POST))` but instead you have used `if(empty($_POST))`

Comment: if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])){ ..}

Comment: !empty i have tried already but it was not running in that way also so i was just checking if its empty and then its running or not........................Isset i have checked but i think it is not setting the submit button

Comment: Avoid using `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` as it is open to vulnerabilities. Instead write the name of the current page. If you need the the form action to be flexible, consider validating the value first.

Comment: value is being validated by jquery if you would have seen the code and surely i will try writing the file name if it helps or not

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: no i am using php 5.6 and i will try using this and see if this solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistake. I dont know how but the value of the forms were not only transferred to this php file but also in another php file names check-email.php which was part of my project which was not mentioned anywhere in register.php.

I got to know the problem by seeing some post related to this kind of problem on stack overflow where he said to check you PHP_error_log and Apache error log. The error was clearly stated there. By doing some changes to check-email.php it is working fine now. Thank you everybody for your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only running if the `$_POST` array is empty.

Change your code to the following.

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

Other than that, I see no problems.

Comment: no that was done for checking purpose before that it was not empty only

Answer (score 1):

It's better practice to take the submit button as a centre of attention for the execution of the server side coding executing.

Therefore check if the $_POST data has been sent using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // the data has successfully been sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure is's ok ?

```
if(empty($_POST))
```

you always execute code in if if $_POST is empty

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

execute when $_POST **NOT** empty

Comment: sorry but that i was trying if my code is getting any values in the $_POST or not.....if i do not empty it will not execute the code

Comment: @NikunjMangla what you get when use var_dump($_POST)? after send form ?

Comment: array(0) { } this value is shown before and after submitting.....it feels like the sign up button is not submitting the value

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem, but generally the submit button is

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

rather than

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

From: [W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: as i said in my post it was working previously and now it isnt then it cant be the case

Comment: this is my original code only.....do you want to see one which is implemented in mysql which is working

Comment: I quickly tried your code, without Sqlserver, and when I clicked submit, nothing happened. I changed it to an <input>, and it did something.

Comment: what did it do because i also tried to changed that to input then also nothing happened

Comment: Well, when I clicked the <button>, nothing happened. When I clicked the <input>, the page reloaded

Comment: Is anything happening? Normally, the page would get reloaded, and your PHP would be run again. Try using GET, instead of POST, so you can see if anything is happening.